# Use join table to display data in admin grid column

Tags: magento2, admin, grid, sorting, join-table

How can I use join table to display second table data in admin grid? Admin grid is created using layout & block in proper manner.

I used this link ([how to create a grid without using ui component in magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/218818/how-to-create-a-grid-without-using-ui-component-in-magento-2)) as reference.

Using below code I display data

```
<block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" name="recipient_email">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Recipient Email</argument>
                        <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">recipient_email</argument>
                        <argument name="renderer" xsi:type="string">Comapny\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Widget\Grid\Column\Renderer\Recipientemail</argument>

                </block>
```

But issue while searching & sorting

I am using this for overriding the default module of enterprise (gift card account)

Code of

> Company/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Widget/Grid/Column/Renderer/Recipientemail.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Company\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Widget\Grid\Column\Renderer;

class Recipientemail extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column\Renderer\AbstractRenderer
{
    protected $_storeManager;


    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Context $context,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,      
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item $orderItem,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;      
        $this->orderitem =  $orderItem;  
    }


    public function render(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $row)
    {

        $code = $row->getCode();
        $result = array();
        $salesorderitem =  $this->orderitem->getCollection()
                          ->addFieldToFilter('product_options', array('like' => '%'.$code.'%'));

        if(!empty($salesorderitem)) 
        {
            foreach($salesorderitem as $orderdata){
                $productOptions = $orderdata->getProductOptions();   
                $recipientemail = $productOptions['giftcard_recipient_email'];
                if(!empty($recipientemail)){
                return $recipientemail;
                }else{
                    return '-';
                }
            }
        }else{
               return '-';
        }


    }
    public function getContents($str, $startDelimiter, $endDelimiter) {
        $contents = array();
        $startDelimiterLength = strlen($startDelimiter);
        $endDelimiterLength = strlen($endDelimiter);
        $startFrom = $contentStart = $contentEnd = 0;
        while (false !== ($contentStart = strpos($str, $startDelimiter, $startFrom))) {
          $contentStart += $startDelimiterLength;
          $contentEnd = strpos($str, $endDelimiter, $contentStart);
          if (false === $contentEnd) {
            break;
          }
          $contents[] = substr($str, $contentStart, $contentEnd - $contentStart);
          $startFrom = $contentEnd + $endDelimiterLength;
        }

        return $contents;
      }

}
```

Code for Adminhtml\Grid\Filter\Recipientemail.php

```
<?php
```

namespace Comapny\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Grid\Filter;

class Recipientemail extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column\Filter\Text
{

```
public function getCondition()
{   
    if ($this->getValue() === null) {
        return null;
    }

    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: This will help you https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/182146/magento-2-filter-not-working-while-custom-column-added-on-sales-grid-using-ui-co

Comment: @ChiragPatel The issue with me is that I need to add this functionality in enterprise giftcard module which is not using UI component to display grid & I am not aware with how to filter the grid with second database that also from sales_order_item 'product_options'

Comment: Are you able to display correct data in the grid after join tables?

Comment: I am able to display correct data using xml & /Renderer/Recipientemail.php code but the issue occurs during filter in Filter/Recipientemail.php. I am getting search text box value in   Filter/Recipientemail.php but no idea about how to reload this grid to display data based on filter

Comment: share your join table code.

Comment: In this file Renderer/Recipientemail.php  $salesorderitem =  $this->orderitem->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('product_options', array('like' => '%'.$code.'%')); code is ued to display data. You can refer in my question

Comment: Have you try with use `$this->addFilterToMap()` ?

Comment: I don;t know where to use as I don't have collection. Can you suggest me how to use?

Comment: Instead of `->addFieldToFilter()` use `$this->addFilterToMap()`

Comment: I tried this $salesorderitem =  $this->orderitem->getCollection()->addFilterToMap('product_options', array('like' => '%'.$code.'%')); but not working

Comment: I also added some code of \Grid\Filter\Recipientemail.php file in this file I am getting text box value in $this->getValue(), but no idea how to reload using this value

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" name="recipient_email">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Recipient Email</argument>
                    <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">recipient_email</argument>
                    <argument name="filter" xsi:type="string">Comapny\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Grid\Filter\Recipientemail</argument>
                    <argument name="renderer" xsi:type="string">Comapny\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Widget\Grid\Column\Renderer\Recipientemail</argument>

</block>
```

Comapny\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Grid\Filter\Recipientemail

```
<?php

    namespace Comapny\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Grid\Filter;

    class Recipientemail extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column\Filter\Text
    {

        public function getCondition()
        {
            if ($this->getValue() === null) {
                return null;
            }

            return ['eq' => $this->getValue()];
        }
    }
```

Comment: <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">recipient_email</argument>. Here recipient_email is not in my main table how can filter it. It gives error SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'recipient_email' in 'where clause', query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `magento_giftcardaccount` AS `main_table` WHERE (`recipient_email` = 'abc')

Comment: Can you please provide me this file code Comapny\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Widget\Grid\Column\Renderer\Recipientemail

Comment: Hi @Vijay I have added code in my question